# SNMPD bind error in Ubuntu 14.04 Server

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, snmpd

I am trying to get SNMPD working on my Zenoss server that runs Ubuntu Server 14.04.  I installed it and configured it but when I start it up, i get the following error in syslog:

```
Aug 14 08:19:16 zenoss snmpd[9904]: Turning on AgentX master support.
Aug 14 08:19:16 zenoss snmpd[9904]: Turning on AgentX master support.
Aug 14 08:19:16 zenoss snmpd[9904]: Error opening specified endpoint "udp:127.0.0.1:161"
Aug 14 08:19:16 zenoss snmpd[9904]: Server Exiting with code 1
```

If I run SNMPD at a command line (sudo /usr/sbin/snmpd -f) it works fine.  I did a netstat -oan | grep 161 and there is nothing else binding to port 161.  Here is my config file (comments removed):

```
agentAddress  udp:127.0.0.1:161
view   systemonly  included   .1.3.6.1.2.1.1
view   systemonly  included   .1.3.6.1.2.1.25.1
rocommunity public  localhost
rwcommunity private localhost
rouser   authOnlyUser
sysLocation    Virtual Machine
sysContact     IT Manager
sysServices    72
load   12 10 5
trap2sink    localhost public
master          agentx
```

And my snmpd settings file (comments removed):

```
export MIBS=
SNMPDRUN=yes
SNMPDOPTS='-Lsd -Lf /dev/null -u snmp -g snmp -I -smux -p /var/run/snmpd.pid -c /etc/snmp/snmpd.conf'
TRAPDRUN=no
TRAPDOPTS='-Lsd -p /var/run/snmptrapd.pid'
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem seems to be here:

**-c /etc/snmp/snmpd.conf**

Remove that from your /etc/default/snmpd so it looks like this:

```
SNMPDOPTS='-Lsd -Lf /dev/null -u snmp -g snmp -I -smux,mteTrigger,mteTriggerConf -p /var/run/snmpd.pid'
```

If you want to get snmpd to listen on 0.0.0.0 (or all interfaces) then edit:

/etc/snmp/snmpd.conf

So it looks like this:

```
#  Listen for connections from the local system only
#agentAddress  udp:127.0.0.1:161
#  Listen for connections on all interfaces (both IPv4 *and* IPv6)
agentAddress udp:161,udp6:[::1]:161
```

Restart SNMP.

Comment: Thanks, but I will have to take your word that this is the solution as we don't even have Zenoss anymore.  But hopefully this will be useful to someone else.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a Permission problem.

under normal situations non-root users are not able to bind to ports <1024 in linux.

However if the SNMPD drops it privileges after creating the socket/endpoint then this should not be your issue.

Comment: I'm fairly new to Linux.  How do I check / correct this?

Comment: try to use a different free port (above 1024) in the config file ( agentAddress), if that is working you know that it is a permission problem and can narrow it down with the search engine of your choice.

Comment: No, that didn't work either: Error opening specified endpoint "udp:127.0.0.1:11161".

Comment: Well, I tried using the servers IP address instead (ie: udp:172.16.112.65:161) and that didn't work.  I then tried just commenting out the line entirely and that DID work.  It binds to 0.0.0.0:161.  This will work for me although I didn't really want to allow outside access.

Comment: Running with root privilege got it working

Answer (score 1):

> Error opening specified endpoint "udp:127.0.0.1:161"

This looks like quite a slippery area in the snmpd codebase - not sure if this is a property of snmpd (as part of Net-SNMP) or Debian and friends.

I've encountered this just now in Debian 11.3.

Too lazy to dive into source code, I've managed to find another symptom of the error using `strace`: namely  `strace -f -o /var/trace.txt snmpd -u root -g root` . In the output trace, you get two consecutive bind() calls on 0.0.0.0:161, the first one succeeds, and the second call fails with EADDRINUSE = address already in use. Initially I dodn't notice that there were two consecutive bind() attempts, so I went looking for the culprit using `netstat -lnp`, which yielded no candidates. Then I had a flurry of socket-related keywords emanate from my ageing grey matter, along the lines of TIME_WAIT, SO_LINGER, SO_REUSEADDR (mind that this probably points to TCP only, not UDP) - until I noticed that snmpd itself is actually the culprit!

There's [a Debian bug report along those lines](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=881046), filed in 2017 for snmpd v5.7. I am already at v5.9, and apparently the bug (or similar) is still there.

There's another [bug report filed with Net-SNMP](https://sourceforge.net/p/net-snmp/bugs/2978/) in 2019 for v5.8 - which claims that the first bind() attempt actually stems from the `trapsink` keyword somewhere in the config files, specifying the localhost address, and defaulting to port 161 as well. I've tried following that advice and it doesn't seem to apply to my case.

Mine appears to be the "debian flavoured" bug above. Actually my best bet is to *exclude* (comment out) any references to `agentAddress` anywhere in the config files - in that case, snmpd will end up starting, reported by netstat as listening on 0.0.0.0:161 . If I add my own declaration of `agentAddress`, it must not overlap with the default IP Address (0.0.0.0) which is impossible, or it must contain a different UDP port (or TCP instead of UDP). If I meet that rule, both those sockets become open, do listen and I do get the same response to my SNMP queries from both.

Coupled to that, I've noticed some peculiarities in the "precedence of config files", such as:

- if I specify agentAddress in both `/usr/share/snmp/snmpd.conf` and  `/etc/snmp/snmpd.conf`, the declaration in `/etc/snmp/snmpd.conf` gets ignored, and the one in `/usr/share/snmp/snmpd.conf` prevails - despite the fact that I can see both these files getting open in strace output.
- the debianese systemd wrapper around snmpd, called
  `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/snmpd.service`
  contains some extra cmdline args: `ExecStart=/usr/sbin/snmpd -LOw -I -smux,mteTrigger,mteTriggerConf` that are kind of difficult for me to follow to all their respective resulting effects, and somehow they do affect the MIB's that get loaded (compared to me just running snmpd by hand at the cmdline) - I get the lmSensors MIB loaded if I start snmpd via systemd, otherwise not. Possibly the modules excluded by the `-I -` option are troublesome. Also, the systemd wrapper contains an extra condition: `ConditionPathExists=/etc/snmp/snmpd.conf` . So I cannot just erase /etc/snmp/snmpd.conf. And if I just "touch" an empty file, snmpd starts, but doesn't respond to the lmSensors OID's.

Interesting stuff.

In other words, there are several similar misbehaviors around the default IP and socket to bind, and whether this gets overridden by an explicit agentAddress (or collides with it). Plus, based on what different people report as workarounds, the precedence of config files can also differ between distroes. It is curious to me that this sounds like a fairly boring area of the codebase, and it has bugs - and yet the arcane SNMP engine and modular architecture of the thing (pluggable sub-agents) seems rock solid.